# restore dom object on hover event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a `hover` event. In order to achieve this, I need to keep the initial element state before execute the function.

```
obj.prototype.onhover = function(callback){
    window.hoverElement = this.element; //store element in global variable before changing its state.
    this.element.onmouseover = function(){
        callback(this);
    };
    this.element.onmouseout = function(){
        console.log(window.hoverElement,this); //why these 2 elements are the same?
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(window.hoverElement,this); //restore initial state
        delete window.hoverElement;
    };
};
```

However, `console.log` output exactly the same element.

What's wrong with my code? Why does `window.hoverElement` store the element that has already changed? And how could I fix it?

Comment: `this` is referring to the hovering element. which is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will understand it by reading the comments below:

```
obj.prototype.onhover = function(callback){
    window.hoverElement = this.element; // 'window' is a global variable. 'this' refers to the obj scope.
    this.element.onmouseover = function(){
        callback(this);
    }.bind(this);
    this.element.onmouseout = function(){
        console.log(window.hoverElement,this); // 'this' is referring to hovered element scope. So, window.hoverElement === this
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(window.hoverElement,this); //restore initial state
        delete window.hoverElement;
    }.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Actually, `this` on the first line refers to `obj` scope.

Comment: So how could I restore the initial dom object in this case?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and some errors occurred. Thank you anyway.